# mysql select view_definition returns multiple definitions

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I am trying to get view definition query for a given `view` in the database.

```
SELECT VIEW_DEFINITION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS WHERE TABLE_NAME='vw_malakar';
```

It gives me two different definitions for the same `view name`.
[image]

Is it possible for the same view with multiple definitions?

Also, which one is the recent one?

Comment: They could be in different schemas.

Comment: Use `SELECT *` to see if any of the columns are different.

Comment: No, it is not possible for a view to have multiple definitions. You have two different views with the same name in two different schemas (databases). As @Barmar suggested, select all fields from  the views table and you will see the difference between the two.